# Fetching templates via API. Who provides this service?

Tags: website-design, api, template, information-retrieval

I'm mainly a server side developer. I'm not a designer, even if I understand web layouts, grids, CSS, typography, valid markup, etc. and I'm able to do some graphic work too (almost). It just takes a lot of time and the result is not always beautiful.

I know there are tons of [website templates sites](https://www.google.com/search?q=website%20templates) out there, and I'd like to use their designs as a starting point for my customers' works, giving them the possibility to choose the design they like more.

I'd just prefer to show the templates catalog to customers from within my site, fetching templates info (screenshots, description, etc) from a remote server using an API. [TemplateMonster.com](http://www.templatemonster.com) provides, or provided, [such API](http://www.templatemonster.com/webapi/). But the service responds with "Unauthorized usage".

Are there other sites offering this kind of retrieval service?

Comment: Most sites have 'predictable' live preview links, which you should be able to open in a modal/iframe without much fuss. I did that with freecsstemplates.org.

Answer (score 1):

If you're worried about your customers finding out what template site you purchased the design from I wouldn't link to it in anyway be it a modal iframe etc. I would suggest you get full size screen shots and put them into a gallery. None have any API that I know of to let you fetch template data be it a link to the template page, screen shots, or live demos.